# Why is my Honda generator running rough, if at all?

Tags: generator, engine

Currently trying to diagnose the issue with my Honda Eu1000i Generator.

- New spark plug
- Changed oil
- Changed gas
- Cleaned entire carburetor

Had the engine running rough for a while and haven't gotten it back there. I can use starting fluid sprayed and it runs well until starting fluid is over.

I don't think it is getting gas, although when it was running it did run for about 30 minutes. This "fluke running" was before starting fluid applied but after the other listed items for cure.

[image][image]

Comment: You say the carb was cleaned, but fuel is most often obstructed by debris in the small passageways. How did you clean it?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the likes of Seafoam have brought many a gunked-up carb back into service even without disassembly.

Comment: How old is the fuel?

Comment: How is the air cleaner? Are you spraying the starter fluid on it, or taking it off and spraying into the barrel? If starter fluid gets it going, the issue likely lies in air/fuel.

Comment: @isherwood I took carb apart, cleaned it, and ran all my carb cleaners and cleaning tools to get it back in shape.it was absolutely gunked up.

Comment: Fuel is brand new after emptying the tank and letting evaporation happen for a few days.

Answer (score 1):

These Honda EU engines are known for carburetor issues when they're not exercised regularly. I tend to run mine *under a load* about monthly. It's quite a common issue in RV circles.

But given that you've already cleaned it, I might look at replacing the fuel pump. Or, honestly, I'd probably swap out the carb for a new one.

Comment: A person could almost certainly stabilize the fuel and run the carb dry for storage rather than pumping high-emissions exhaust into the air for no reason.

Comment: And then drain the fuel and put it in your car or lawnmower. My old Honda engine has a plug on the bottom of the carb that lets you do both at once.